# Definition of the umbilical points

Tags: differential-geometry

I am just a little confused about why if a point p is umbilical then −dN(p) is a scalar multiple of the identity map. It is kinda "obvious" in all resources I've found so I guess I am just missing something really obvious.

Comment: Isn't that the definition? A $2\times 2$ matrix is a scalar multiple of the identity if and only if it has two equal eigenvalues.

Comment: Oh that's what I was missing... get it now! Thank you very much:)